# MouseEvent is not a constructor | PhantomJS / Selenium WebDriver (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I copy and pasted the following code directly from my DevTool's console into a `driver.execute_script` block. When executing from the browser, the observed behavior is as I expect it to be. However, when executing via `execute_script`, I get a `MouseEvent is not a constructor` error from Selenium

Here's the code

```
self.driver.execute_script('''
        var mousedownEvent = new MouseEvent('mousedown');
        mousedownEvent.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true);
        arguments[0].dispatchEvent(mousedownEvent);
''', dropdown_container.find_element_by_css_selector('span.select2-chosen'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that PhantomJS does not support the API I was using for creating the mouse event.

Instead, this is the code I used:

```
self.driver.execute_script('''
    var me = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    me.initEvent(
        "mousedown",
        true,
        true,
    );
    arguments[0].dispatchEvent(me);
''', my_element)
```

I couldnt find any documentation regarding supported APIs for events etc on PhantomJS' website, nor did I see much in GhostDriver outside the source code. **I'll leave this question open in case someone does know where the information is located, and can post a more detailed explanation**